# Change DatePickerDialog buttons to text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

Hi i want to adjust my `DatePickerDialog`, and instead of buttons at the bottom (displayed on image below) i just want to make blue text.

[image]

Here is how i created DatePickerDialog

```
private val birthdayDate by lazy {
    Calendar.getInstance()
}
private val datePicker by lazy {
    DatePickerDialog(
        context,
        R.style.MyDatePickerDialogTheme,
        this,
        birthdayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        birthdayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        birthdayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    ).also {
        it.datePicker.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
    }
}
```

Then i just call show method to display the dialog. I think problem is somewhere in my `style`, but i can not find where. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker this library has the view as you require

Comment: I am not sure, but i think it is possible to achieve without external library

Comment: okay , let me check again

Answer (score 19):

So i finally found the solution. I added extra fields in `MyDatePickerDialogTheme` and extra style for buttons used in `DatePicker`. Solution looks like that:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with MaterialDesign you could use this.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(parent.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(parent.getContext(), 
(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
     Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     selectedDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
     }, 
calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePicker.show();
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/darkgray</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    <item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
</style>
```

This style will lead to have no outlined or filled box buttons. Your cancel and confirm buttons will appear in colorAccents color.

Answer (score 0):

as listed in this [link](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-datepickerdialog-theme.html)
you can use this theme

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);
```

to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

The current most voted answer changes the default `minHeight` and `minWidth` of buttons compared to the default date picker.
To correct this I had to specify these attributes in the custom style.
I was able to find the standard attribute for `minWidth`, but default `minHeight` has `54dp` value in the runtime and I couldn't find this value anywhere among standard Android values.
This example uses Material themes directly.

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  .....
  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary<item>
  <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerButtonStyle</item>
  <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless">
  <item name="android:minHeight">54dp</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/mtrl_btn_dialog_btn_min_width</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```